# Event Listener Running Function Before The Element Is Clicked In Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

I have recently been creating an extension for Google Chrome and the manifest version 2 says that I cannot use event handlers(onclick,onmouseover,ondblclick etc.) INSIDE the html files that I create. It does say that I can create them on the script that I link to it. The only problem is that when I click the icon, the function runs before I click the actual div element. I'm really confused on what I did wrong so I've tried it a couple ways:

My manifest.json file seems to be working fine, I don't get any errors and every page linked works, as well as the icon.png file.

```
{
    "name" : "Test",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "description" : "Trying it out",
    "browser_action" : {
"default_icon" : "icon.png",
"defalut_title" : "Test",
"default_popup" : "popup.html"
},
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
"newtab" : "newtab.html"
}
}
```

Here is what I put in my popup.html file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="submitButton">Submit!</div>
</body>
</html> <!-- The rest of the code is unnecessary since it is not used as for now -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

My popup.js file has this function:

```
var sButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
sButton.addEventListener('onclick',alert('This is not supposed to happen until I click the div'),false);

//I also put the alert in a function like so: function() {alert('what it said')}
```

After I noticed that this way didn't work, I went with this:

```
sButton.onclick = function() {alert('same thing')}
```

Either of the ways I did it would alert when I clicked the extension icon and it didn't even run the popup.html. I don't know if I need to add a function to it but since I'm new to this (my first extension) I don't really know if I'm supposed to add a special chrome method or something. I've looked through the Google Dev page but it didn't help. It only taught me the basics.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your call to `addEventListener` needs to pass a function; you're passing the return value from a call to `alert()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
sButton.addEventListener('click',
    function() {alert('This is not supposed to happen until I click the div'),false);});
```

You're calling `alert()` and passing its result to `addEventListener`. You need to pass a function that will call `alert()`.

BTW, when specifying the event in `addEventListener`, you don't include the `on` prefix -- it's just `click`.

Comment: So if I want to pass a function, I'd have to do something like this?:

    sButton.addEventListener('onclick',
    function() {myFunctionCall()},false);

Comment: If you just want to pass a named function, you can do `sButton.addEventListener('click', myFunctionCall)`. You only need to wrap it in `function() {...}` if you need to specify arguments to the function, as in your alert.

Comment: Thank you for yoru help. I've tried both onclick and just click but they seem to not be working. I'll try what you said right now and update on what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: It's working perfectly thank you so much for your help... Sorry I didn't edit my other comment, it didn't let me so I had to create a new one. Thanks again though.

Comment: There's a time limit on how long you can wait between writing and editing a comment, I think it's 5 minutes.